# How do I show my wallet from the command line?

Tags: wallet, linux

How can I show/open my wallet in gui-less linux version? I tried to show the contents with `cat` but it's only binary data (which makes sense). The `--help` option of `bitcoin/bin/64/bitcoind` also doesn't give me a hint.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Direct command-line access via `bitcoind` is not available any more. You *can* get access from the command line via the RPC (Remote Procedure Call) API, e.g. with python. The API calls list is found [here](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Original_Bitcoin_client/API_calls_list).

To give a specific example, you can access wallet information via the [Python RPC](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/API_reference_%28JSON-RPC%29) API. Given that the client was booted with `rpcuser=user` and `rpcpassword=pass`, the sample python script illustrates how you can call the `getbalance` command:

```
  from jsonrpc import ServiceProxy

  access = ServiceProxy("http://user:pass:8332")
  access.getinfo()
  access.listreceivedbyaddress(6)
  print access.getbalance()
```

Comment: This needs updating, it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: @erikvoid Updated to reflect the current state of things.